# RouteUrl and RouteLink not working

Tags: .net, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I just upgraded to MVC3 final and a part of my site that used to work has totally stopped working. Any idea where my URL's have gone or how to get them back?

**Global**

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "SingleArticle",
            "Articles/{action}/{year}/{month}/{day}/{key}", 
            new { controller = "Articles", action = "Archive", year = 0, month = 0, day = 0, key = "" },
            new { year = @"\d{4}", month = @"\d{2}", day = @"\d{2}" }
        );
```

**cshtml**

```
        var routeLinkData = new { 
        action = "Archive", 
        year = item.PublishDate.Value.Year, 
        month = item.PublishDate.Value.Month, 
        day = item.PublishDate.Value.Day, 
        key = item.NameKey };

        URL="@Url.RouteUrl("SingleArticle", routeLinkData)"
        Link="<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("SingleArticle", routeLinkData)">Link</a>"
```

**Output**

```
       URL=""
       Link="<a href="">Link</a>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually turned out to be a change in the need for default values for routes and incorrect regular expressions.